# How to show that $f_{n+1} \leq f_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let $$f_n(t) = \frac{e^{nt}-e^{-nt}}{e^{nT}-e^{-nT}}$$
be defined on $t \in [0,T]$.

Can someone help me, I need to prove that $f_{n+1}(t) \leq f_n(t)$ for every $t$.

I tried taking ratios and/or multiplying top and bottom by by $e^{nT}$ but it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you know $\sinh$ and $\cosh$? Those can help here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$f_{n+1}-f_n=\sinh ((n+1) t) \text{csch}((n+1) T)-\sinh (n t) \text{csch}(n T)$$

Comment: Is it obvious from this?

Comment: I mean $\csch$ is decreasing but $\sinh$ is increasing which doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

$d /dx \, (e^{xt} - e^{-xt}) = t (e^{xt} + e^{-xt})$, which is increasing in $t$ (you can verify this by differentiation with respect to $t$).  This means that in the expression above the denominator increases more rapidly than the numerator as $n$ increases, and so $f_n(t)$ is decreasing in $n$.